# React Native App in google Playstore always give same size of update, every-time I Release new Updates (android only)

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification

i have a application which is completely made with RN and it is released in google play store.

i am creating release with `./gradlew bundleRelease` command which will create a bundle unlike apk,  also recommended by RN

ref. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android#generating-the-release-apk

now i am confuse that everytime  i upload a new update i have to download a complete apk even if the update is so small

**Note: I m not trying to reduce the app size here this is just to inform**

please help me in this. i have used proGard also in the android part to minimise the app size

Comment: woah, i get your doubt . even i have the same question.

Comment: have you checked this doc about [Android App Bundles](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle)? It has different functionality. If you want to achieve reduced app update size, [File-by-File patching](https://github.com/google/archive-patcher/blob/master/README.md) might help you.

Comment: @Niraj i don't want to reduce app size. app bundle is not for that. i am just uploading app bundle to app console and it is creating update of same size to user who got the update in the device

Comment: @Jigar As [this image](https://developer.android.com/images/app-bundle/aab_format-2x.png) shows, whenever you'll upload app update, the update size will be your `base module`, the app will download `feature 1` and `feature 2` only when needed.

Comment: how to config that feature 1 and 2 ? @Niraj

Comment: Just to get your question right, you didn't want user to download a new apk from PlayStore when a small changes are made on your app?

Comment: @TommyLeong sorry for my bad english, i just mean to say, when i upload a new update into google playstore as a developer and when user see that my app got new update in google play. then that update is exact of new app size even after user already have the previous version installed.